# Laptop shutdown right after lid is closed

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, shutdown, sleep, lid

I own an ASUS G750JS, which never had a problem till now. When I am on my computer and I close the lid for the night, it suddenly shuts down. Sometimes it goes to sleep but 90 percent of the time its shutting down.

Please don't tell me to go to the power options -> what happens when lid closes.

- I have tried hibernation
- I have gone to command prompt and turned on hibernation.
- I have also set the laptop to do nothing and it still happens.
- I have also done a factory restore complete wipe.
- I have updated every driver that I have going one by one in the device manager.

I am a computer engineering student and have asked ton's of people and everyone goes, "that's weird."   Please any real help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have ypu check if there is a BIOS update? Another hypothesis: does your machine have heating problems? (It starts doimg some task like AV overnight, heats up and shuts itself down). You might want to look at your windows logs too, just in case.

Comment: Why not look in the Event Viewer after you turn the computer back on to find out which process initiated the shutdown? You can do this by starting Event Viewer (`WinKey+R -> "eventvwr" -> Enter`) and navigating to `Windows Logs -> System`) and then click on `Filter current log` and replace **<All Event IDs>** with **1074**. If the process that initiated it is anything other than `explorer.exe` or `winlogon.exe` you might want to add that information to your question.

Comment: Have you run any hardware diagnostics to ensure there are no failing components?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be a few possibilities which I would try to list as below:
Note: For your case, I assume that you mean "sleep" as in "standby/suspend to ram" (S3), not "save program state in HDD" as in "Hibernation mode" (S4), based  on ACPI spec:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface
ie. Sleep => program state is saved in RAM (all lost when power out), Hibernation => program state is saved in HDD. Not affected by power loss.

1. Possibility: **Battery issue**

Could it be because the battery could not hold charge or battery controller circuit is not stable. You mentioned after "close the lid for the night", "90% of the time it shut down". It could be because the laptop lost power and all program state saved on RAM became lost due to power outage.

You may trouble-shoot this issue by removing battery, and leave the power connected to the unit without battery. If the problem goes away when you remove battery, then you can rule out OS/System issue.

2. Possibility: **OS issue**

You can check EVENT VIEWER in windows by:
1. Start -> Run -> type "eventvwr" or you can access via Control Panel
2. Once inside Event Viewer, select "System Log" (or other log) to check for error message that may give you a better clue.

You can trouble-shoot this issue by Re-installing Windows (Fresh Install, or Factory Recovery) after backing up all your data. You may also set up a Dual-Boot to Linux to see if the behaviour is the same under Linux. If the behaviour is normal under Linux, there is a good chance that it's issue in Windows OS.

3. Possibility: **BIOS issue**

You may contact the tech support or manufacturer website to get the latest BIOS that may have solve earlier bugs.

4. Possibility: **Motherboard issue**

It could be some component is near damage so the behaviour become unstable. If after you tried everything else mentioned above and the problem still remains, it's most likely a motherboard issue.

Comment: One other possible issue: on one laptop, I've noticed that if there is an open internet connection, shutdown takes a looong time. Test shutting WiFi first, to see if that's the issue... but I don't have a one-step shutdown procedure suggestion, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

My system (windows 8.1 64bit) started restarting upon closing the lid or going into sleep mode after I changed the windows update settings to download but don't install. I then changed it to check for updates but dont download and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For the long shut-down, you could try disabling the "Hybrid boot" (windows fast start, which is effectively kind of a hybernation procedure it does when you shut it down). For the unexpected shutdown when the lid is closed - almost sounds like a config conflict... are you relying on Windows Power Manager settings alone or did your computer come with additional manufacturers "Power Manager" software of it's own? Perhaps one of them is overriding the settings of the other?